# Webpack Dev Server Issues

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-4

I am building a web application using Express + React.

I am dealing with a issue with WEbpack Dev Server.

My Webpack Dev Server builds the bundles just fine!
But, I have an issue with the way the files are served.

Usually , we name the root html file as index.html, but because of my Web application architecture , I cannot use index.html and have instead name it client.html.

This brings me to the problem that I am facing, the webpack dev server looks for the index.html when I go to localhost:8080, as I am using client.html the webpack dev serves asks me to select my file.

[Webpack Static file select screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2JtY.png)

So , is there a way to load client.html directly when I access localhost:8080(Webpack Dev Server).

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `webpack.config.js` file you can add the configurations for the webpack dev server

```
devServer: {
  historyApiFallback: {
    rewrites : [
      {from: /^\/$/, to: './client.html'}
    ]
  }
}
```

This will redirect your default *index.html* to the *client.html*
For more details see the [DevServer documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-historyapifallback)

Comment: Thanks You So Much! It Worked!